# How can I create a segue between a custom UITableViewCell button and a second view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue, custom-cell

I created a custom UITableViewCell in a separate nib, and inside it I have a button. I want the tableViewCell to segue to one view controller when the cell is tapped, but a different one when the button is tapped. The cell tap segue works fine, but I can't figure out how to setup a segue between the button in the cell and the next view. I have added a target to the button with

```
cell.imagePreview.addTarget(self, action: "segueToImageView:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Then in that method

```
@IBAction func segueToImageView(sender: UIButton) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("ImageViewSegue", sender: self)
}
```

But obviously I end up with a "has no segue with identifier 'ImageViewSegue'" error. I tried connecting the button to the new view in my main.storyboard, but it won't let me drag between the nib and the storyboard. I also tried creating a segue in main.storyboard between the two views and calling it "ImageViewSegue" but I get the same error.

Is there a way to create a segue with identifier through code? If not, how should I go about segueing to the new view via the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a segue, just do this the old-fashioned way (from before there were storyboards and segues): set the button's action–target pair (in code, when you load) so that when the button is tapped, your action handler is called. In the action handler, do whatever the segue would do, i.e. instantiate the view controller from the storyboard and push or present it.

Comment: I'm new to iOS development and started after storyboards were a thing, so I didn't even know that was possible. I thought a segue was what it's always called to transition from one view to another. You totally solved my problem. Thanks so much!